# How to find files and directories that are taking too much space in Linux?

Tags: linux

In Windows I could easily do this by navigating the directory tree and looking at the sizes. But in Linux, you need to run a command and, what's worse, it takes *a lot* of time:

```
$ du -sh /some/dir
```

I'm using a disk of 1 TB, but for some reason I only have like 50 GB left, and I can't seem to find what's taking so much space.

I remember that in Ubuntu I had to manually remove old kernel images. But now I'm on Fedora and `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` doesn't work, and I guess Fedora removes them automatically anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to find big files in your disk with a command such as:

```
find . -size +100M -type f -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

In this example, only files with 100 Mega Bytes (units of 1048576 bytes) or more are displayed.  That value can be tweaked as you please.

Comment: btw - since you want to avoid processing `/proc` .. I made the following adjustment to your command: `for dname in *; do if [ $dname != "proc" ]; then find $D -size +10M -type f -exec ls -lh {} \;; fi; done` (presumes running from `/`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1
```

You can use with [tree](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-directory-structure-command-line/) also

```
tree -h >> file
```